# Show Joomla article tags in override of newsflash module

Tags: joomla

We would like to create an override for the Joomla newsflash module which should be able to display the individual Joomla article tags on the frontend:
   "tag 1, tag 2, tag 3 etc.."

RokSproket from rockettheme.com is able to achieve exactly that output. But we would like to have the same result with the newsflash module. We currently have the following code saved in our new _item.php override. There is no error message on the frontend but also no tags are visible. Any help is much appreciated.

```
<?php if ($params->get('show_tags', 1) && !empty($item->tags)) : ?>
    <?php $item->tagLayout = new JLayoutFile('joomla.content.tags'); ?>

    <?php echo $item->tagLayout->render($item->tags->itemTags); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You might like to post your question on the Joomla Stack Exchange site to gain the attention of a more dedicated audience. Note, in your **Administrator** -> **Help** tab, the 2nd last item says **Stack Exchange** <-- this is where the Joomla team encourages you to post your Joomla-specific questions and issues when you need support.  Always turn on errors from your Global Configuration when debugging, and seek out any potential server-side & client-side errors because these messages are super helpful when volunteers wish to offer assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how we've solved that question:

```
<?php       
$itemtags = (new JHelperTags)->getItemTags('com_content.article', $item->id);
$taglayout = new JLayoutFile('joomla.content.tags');
$tags='';
if( !empty($itemtags) )
    $tags = '<div class="itemtags">'.str_replace(',','',$taglayout->render($itemtags)).'</div>';
     ?>
<?php echo $tags; ?>
```